# Dynamic generation of javadoc

Tags: maven, javadoc

I have a project which generates javadoc.

I have another project which uses a part of the above project. Is it possible to define an execution that will only generate javadoc from the above project to what I define it to (include only specific package)?

Currently I have a javadoc dependency on the above project which gives me the whole javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes and no. You can configure the [maven-javadoc-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) to exclude packages (and consequently include other packages) by using the [<excludePackageNames>](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/exclude-package-names.html) tag, e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
       <excludePackageNames>com.excluded.package.*</excludePackageNames>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Depending on your use-case (and the effort required), another feasible solution would be to split the current project into two separate projects, say `com.company.example.api` and `com.company.example.implementation`, and then only generate the javadoc for the `api` project.